# How to show all products of a specific author in a shortcode?

Tags: php, woocommerce

Can you tell me how to display all the products of a certain user (the one who added the product) Woocommerce using a shortcode? I almost managed to create this code, but it gives this error:

> Warning: Array to string conversion in /var/www/

What am I doing wrong?

```
add_shortcode( 'author_products', 'products_current_author' );
 
function products_current_author() {
$args = [
    'author_name'    => 'andrey',
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'fields'         => 'ids',
];

$ids[] = get_posts( $args );
    
    
    return do_shortcode( '[products ids="' . join( ",", array_unique( $ids) ) . '"]' );
 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem on my own. Here is the working code, tested, working.

```
add_shortcode( 'author_products', 'author_products_shortcode' );
   
function author_products_shortcode() {
// Get the author ID Outside loop.
    global $post;
    $author_id = $post->post_author;

   $args = array(
      'author'    => $author_id,
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'fields' => 'ids',
   );
    
   $product_ids = get_posts( $args ); 
   $product_ids = implode( ",", $product_ids );
    
   return do_shortcode("[products ids='$product_ids']");
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to provided code, to display all products by product author, using woocommerce, the following code can be checked:

```
add_shortcode( 'author_products', 'products_current_author' );
function products_current_author() {
    $args = [
        'author_name'    => 'andrey',
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        'fields'         => 'ids',
    ];
    $ids = get_posts( $args );
    echo do_shortcode( '[products ids="' . join( ",", array_unique( $ids) ) . '"]' ); 
}
```

It can be checked, if this code works.

Comment: You right, The provided code by OP is incorrect, but the question title is about to get products by author, not `ID`.